# In new version of MacOS I had to switch to zsh, now I have to add double quotes around parameters otherwise it wont work

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I would like to get old bash behavior back is this possible ?

With bash I was writing simple:

```
youtube-dl https://www...
```

Now I have to write:

```
youtube-dl "https://www..."
```

Also in other commands I have seen similar behavior.. This is not user-friendly and I don't see any improvement over bash in general, I just need it it work as bash anyway, but somehow apple made zsh default now.

So do I need to get Bash back to get old behavior or is it possible to configure Zsh to be not so strict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when you use an argument that contains a filename wildcard character without quoting or escaping it. In this case, it's probably the `?` in a URL with parameters. What happens is that since there's a wildcard, it tries to expand it to a list of matching filenames, and since there aren't any it either leaves it alone (bash) or throws a "no matches found" error (zsh).

The best solution is to properly quote or escape any arguments with wildcard that you don't want expanded, because occasionally one *will* match one or more files, and your command will do something you didn't expect.

You don't want to do that? Ok, it's your funeral. You have a several options:

1. Tell zsh to allow unmatched wildcard expressions. Add this command to your ~/.zshrc:

   ```
   setopt nonomatch
   ```

   (`nonomatch` means "no nomatch", i.e. remove the "nomatch" option, which is what makes it throw an error on unmatched wildcards.)
2. Switch back to bash. zsh is now the default interactive shell, but you can change this in your account settings. The simplest way is to run `chsh -s /bin/bash`. However, Apple added a warning about bash being replaced by zsh. If you don't want to see that every time you open a shell, add this to your ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, or ~/.profile (whichever exists):

   ```
   export BASH_SILENCE_DEPRECATION_WARNING=1
   ```
3. You could install an up-to-date version of bash and use that instead. See ["Update bash to version 4.0 on OSX"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193411/update-bash-to-version-4-0-on-osx) on Ask Different (note: bash is now up to v5.something, but the same methods work).

Comment: I tried switching to bash but, somehow all commands wont work.. its probably because of paths are not setup for some reason ?  Look like zsh is using bash files but zsh is not so to move to bash I need to move all commands from .zshrc  and zprofile to bash versions ? 

Ok nevermind I have "setopt nonomatch" now in .zshrc and works good. Thank you.