# How do I clear this terminal message?

Tags: zsh

This popped up in my terminal after loading the Monterey OS on my Mac Book Pro.
What steps do I take, in what order to correct this error message?

> The default interactive shell is now zsh.
> To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.

For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050

Comment: It's not an error message, it's an information message. Apple changed the default shell from bash to zsh. Did you read the link?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve:  Stick with your current login shell and just make the warning go away, or switch to zsh?

Answer (score 1):

It's not an error, just an informational message. I believe it only shows up the first time you run a shell after upgrading. If you want to start using `zsh`, follow the instructions in that message. If you're happy running `bash` or whatever shell you're currently on, you don't need to take any action. I don't think you'll see that message again from that account.

Comment: The annoying message appears every time I ssh into an account using BASH.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fix to suppress that terminal message when BASH starts up:

```
export BASH_SILENCE_DEPRECATION_WARNING=1
```

From: [In new version of MacOS I had to switch to zsh, now I have to add double quotes around parameters otherwise it wont work](https://superuser.com/questions/1722443)